# OctoberCms How to pass ajax response to javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, octobercms, october-partial

I created a form in my component html file, When i submit a form an ajax call triggers to my action defined in component. So far my code is working fine i'm getting response. But now i want the response to be passed to the javscript function that i created inside component htm file.

```
function markAddresses(addresses) {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
addresses.forEach(address => {
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status === 'OK') {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: results[0].geometry.location});
       } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
   }
  });
  })
```

}

I want to pass my response like markAddresses(response)

```
<form method="post" data-request="onSend">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">

    <select name="service[]" id="services" class="form-control">&nbsp;
        {% for client in records %}
            <option value="{{ client.service }}">{{ client.service }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="area[]" id="search" class="form-control" >&nbsp;
        {% for client in records %}
            <option value="{{ client.area }}">{{ client.area }} Miles</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="submit" value="Looks for Shops" class="red-btn btn btn-default">
    <a class="location-view" href="#">View all Shops</a>
</div>
```

This is how my Ajax is working. I think it is using octobercms Ajax framework

Comment: can you share your ajax request form markup, how you are making ajax call

Comment: @HardikSatasiya shared

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-attributes-api`

```html
<form method="post" 
      data-request="onSend" 
      data-request-success="markAddresses(data)"
      <!--    ^-- this one -->
>
....
</form>
```

> make sure `markAddresses` is global function you can access it globally. and `data` is return value from the handler.

If your handler looks like this

```php
function onSend() {
    return ['test' => 'data'];
}
```

It will pass object like below in `markAddresses` as variable `data`

```js
console.log(data); // output : { "test": "data" }
```

If any doubt please comment.